# Why overloading unary operator is not working with rvalue in C++?

Tags: c++

I am a new C++ programmer. I am facing an issue while trying to overload unary operator(--) in my code.
Here is the code-

Working Code-

```
Mystring operator--() {
    cout << "I am plus plus" << endl;
    char *x=new char[strlen(this->str)+1];
    size_t i=0;
    while(i<strlen(str)){
        x[i]=tolower(str[i]);
        i++;
    }
    x[i+1]='\0';
    
    Mystring temp{x};
    delete []x;
    return temp;
}
```

Error Code-

```
   Mystring &operator--() {
        cout << "I am plus plus" << endl;
        char *x=new char[strlen(this->str)+1];
        size_t i=0;
        while(i<strlen(str)){
            x[i]=tolower(str[i]);
            i++;
        }
        x[i+1]='\0';
        
        Mystring temp{x};
        delete []x;
        return &temp;
    }
```

Here, Mystring is a class and I am trying to overloading the decrement operator(--) so that it can lowercase all the characters of the class when it is called and return a lowercase instance of Mystring class.
It's working fine. But when I am trying to return an rvalue it's giving me the following error-

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Mystring&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Mystring*’
```

I don't know why it's behavior this way. Can anyone please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Pass "rvalue" and continue reading, it comes to "invalid initialization of type ‘Mystring&’ from type ‘Mystring*’". 2. You are attempting to return a reference to a local variable that goes out of scope on next line.

Comment: You can't bind a non-const reference to an rvalue. But, `&temp` does not create an rvalue. Your 1st code is correct, you need to return `MyString` by value so a copy is returned. Also, in both codes, `x[i+1]='\0';` is an out-of-bounds error. You need to use `i` instead of `i+1`. A better and safer implementation can be made without involving `x` at all. You can create `temp` from `str` and then modify the content of `temp.str`

Comment: aside: `cout << "I am plus plus" << endl;` in `operator --`?

Comment: The prefix `--` and `++` operators are generally expected to modify `*this` and return (a reference to) it, not create a new object. Don't abuse overloading, it only causes problems.

Comment: If the local variable will go out of scope, then why it works in terms of function returns? For example,if you return a rvalue from a function it works. Why it's not working in terms of constructor?